# Find all possible combinations of a specific word (string) using any combination of upper case and lower case letters with a for loop (no itertools)

Tags: python, string, algorithm, loops, for-loop

Using Python Language
e.g.

`string = hat`

`combo = ['hat', 'Hat', 'HAt', 'HAT', 'hAT', 'haT', 'HaT', 'hAt']`

What I've tried so far

```
    gear = ['hat']

for i in range(len(gear[0])):
    gearlist1 = list(gear[0])
    gearlist2 = [c.upper() for c in gearlist1]
    gearlist3 = [gearlist1[0].join(gearlist2)]


print 'list is: %r' % (gearlist3 ,),
```

Comment: Hi user3323799. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far?

Comment: I created 2 lists; one where the letters are lower cases and one that changed all of the the lowercase list to upper cases. I'm stuck at trying to find a way to merge them and then add them to a new list.

Comment: You would get a better answer to your problem if you showed us your code and described the specific issue that you are having with it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more detail - at the moment your question fits into the "Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem" category.

Comment: is there a way I could PM you?

Comment: AFAIK StackOverflow doesn't have that functionality.

Comment: @starsplusplus you can create chat rooms for that purpose. However it's best to keep things in the question so it's all useful to others in the future.

Comment: @Amicable True but PM stands for *private* message and the one-on-one chats are publicly readable I believe? (I've not actually used them.)

Comment: @starsplusplus It's more an IM service than a PM service `Gallery: anyone may enter, but only approved users can talk` so yes they are publically readable. There is no reason to privately talk about solving an SO question though, as the whole point is that they are meant to be useful for future readers.

Comment: @Amicable Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to think about the problem - iterate over all binary strings of the same length as your input string and for each binary string use uppercase where the binary string has `1` and lowercase where it has `0`. You can use a simple bitmask to generate all possible binary strings of a given length.

Comment: +1 for giving a way to think about the problem rather than providing code straight out the gate.

Comment: I'm new to coding, I don't know much about iterating and bitmask.

Comment: @user3323799 that is a great reason to browse the web and find out what they are and how to use them!

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I'm required to use what I've learnt so far to do this problem. (i.e loops, if n else, strings, lists)

Comment: @user3323799 yeap this should be more than enough. I suggest a simple loop(i.e. a for cycle) over bitmasks i.e. using bitwise operators on integer numbers

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I forgot to mention this is python language

Comment: @user3323799 this is very important bit and is the most important thing to tag when you ask a question. My answer is general as you have not identified a particular language. And you got downvoted(not by me) because you have not shown any effort to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I've but in a lot of effort. Stayed up all night trying to figure this out. This is just a small part of a large code. I just need to be able to create this list of strings and I'll be all set.

Comment: If you're new to coding, this problem may not be graded to your level.   It's a question I'd expect out of the second month of a college introductory CS class.

That being said, the amount of effort you've put into it is, unfortunately, fairly irrelevant: computers don't respect effort.  I would strongly suggest you talk with your instructor to find out what background you're missing.